# How to localize a static UITableView section?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, ios7, localization

I have a view with a `UITableView` with one section and one cell.  It's used purely for layout.  The section has a header and a footer, both with some text in it.

I want to localize this text but can't figure out how.  Currently the only way I'm aware of is to implement `titleForHeaderInSection:` but I'd prefer not to do this as it's a static table, and I'd rather avoid having to implement the `UITableViewDelegate` just to accomplish this.  Is there another way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have implemented UITableViewDataSource, you can use NSLocalizedString when implementing tableView:sectionIndexTitlesForTableView: and tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:.

If you are using interface builder, xcode allows you to localize entire xib. But the drawback is that it will create one xib for each locale you need to support.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

I'd prefer not to implement UITableViewDataSource (it would only be for this).

I have my application localized, but the strings set in XCode for header/footer don't show up in my .strings files, and if I add them manually (via "Object-ID") nothing seems to happen.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, strings file is not getting updated as you update the xib. Try using ibtool (ibtool Base.lproj/file.xib --generate-strings-file file.strings). Problem with ibtool is that it doesn't generate strings file incrementally. New file.strings will have all strings in base language. You will have to replace them with localized strings again. Alternatively, you can try AppleGlot (https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action?name=localization)

Comment: OK -- I've found my problem.  Thanks for confirming it can be done, and turning me onto AppleGlot.